# That way I can send a Toast within Intent?

Tags: android, package

I Have 4 buttons in my App, in 2 of these buttons I need to check if the app that I want to run is in my device. If exist, run, else, show a toast.

The problem is when I show a toast, the aplication close. What is the best way to show a Toast in the startActivity(Intent)???

this is the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent LaunchIntent = null;
    boolean isTouch = isAppInstalled("com.enflick.android.ping");
    boolean isWpress = isAppInstalled("org.wordpress.android");


    switch (v.getId()) {
    case (R.id.botonPortafoli):
        LaunchIntent = new Intent(this, PortafoliActivity.class);
        break;
    case (R.id.botonSocial):
        LaunchIntent = new Intent(this, SocialActivity.class);
        break;

    case (R.id.botonTouch):

        if (isTouch) {
            LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    "com.enflick.android.ping");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_inst, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            break;
        }

        break;
    case (R.id.botonWpress):

        if (isWpress) {
            LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    "org.wordpress.android");

            break;

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_inst, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();


            break;
        }

    }
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the app breaks? What does the LogCat say?

Comment: did you try to debug line by line to see where it breaks?

Comment: How can I debug line by line in eclipse?? I might put checkpint in all lines??

Comment: My first try would be change catching exception `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException` to `Exception`, and making sure that the method is not returning true when the application is not instaled.

Comment: You just need to left-click (maybe double click) on the left of the line you want to break the code, you may need to set a property like debugable or something I don't remember, but I thing eclipse does it for you, just asks to do it.

Comment: It looks like in both cases, (whether package is installed or not), your installed. Also you can try calling getInstalledApplications and traverse the list to determine whether the package is installed or not

Comment: you don't need to check all lines, just do a line-step after the program is paused in a breakpoint, it must be F6 or F8, using Visual Studio and Eclipse and NetBeans all of them with different debug keys drive me crazy.

Comment: Thanks, I try all options and make an answer!

Comment: Ok, I update the question for explain.

Comment: Oh well, now you've got a totally different question, I thing there is a method like `getApplicationContext()` and then with this context you can call the `makeToast()` method, that's all from my memory I'm not totally sure about the names.

Comment: I don't find teh makeToast() method... I'm going crazy... jajajajaja

Comment: oh man, forget it if it doesn't make sense, there is some time that I don't program android I forgot the methods names. Also, please mark your comments with @HericDenis or I won't receive a notification that you respond me. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @HericDenis I don't solve the problem... I know what is the problem but not what is the solution. The problem is the Intent what I send. When I find the package, I can send and Intent for execute the package but, if the package don't exist, I don't know what can I send in the Intent for show a Toast message

Comment: Well, I didn't go deep on this programming concept they introduced on android using those intents and stuff, I would suggest you to edit back your question for the first one and start another question with the acctual problem :)
Looks like you need to send some kind of error message via intent but as I told ya I don't know much about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `isAppInstalled("com.enflick.android.ping")` you could surround your call with try/catch. I don't think you can check if the app is installed without actually launching it...

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent();

    if (v.getId() == (R.id.botonPortafoli)) {
        LaunchIntent = new Intent(this, PortafoliActivity.class);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    } else if (v.getId() == (R.id.botonSocial)) {
        LaunchIntent = new Intent(this, SocialActivity.class);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    } else if (v.getId() == (R.id.botonTouch)) {
        try {
            LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    "com.enflick.android.ping");
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_inst, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == (R.id.botonWpress)) {
        try {
            LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    "org.wordpress.android");
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_inst, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you, it did for me when I was trying to verify if the official Twitter app was installed on the device.

By the way, just to be on the safe side, it might be better to use `if-else` instead of `switch` to avoid the resources id not being final issue.